# Querying a JSON column on a boolean field

Tags: python, json, sqlalchemy

I have a `Food` model with a JSON column. I use sqlite3.

```
class Food(Base):

    __tablename__ = "foods"
    properties = Column(JSON)
```

In this JSON `properties` field, I can have several type of fields: string, integer and boolean.

If I want to query `properties` for a string json field:

```
from sqlalchemy import type_coerce
from sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite import JSON

tastes_ok = ["yummy", "beurk"]
coerced_values = [type_coerce(v, JSON) for v in tastes_ok]

foods = session.query(Food).filter(Food.properties["taste"].in_(coerced_values))
```

Or for a json field that contains an integer:

```
number_of_eggs = [1, 2, 3]
coerced_values = [type_coerce(v, JSON) for v in number_of_eggs]

foods = session.query(Food).filter(Food.properties["number_of_eggs"].in_(coerced_values))
```

But this approach doesn't work on booleans:

```
is_it_good = [True, False]
# is_it_good = [True]  # doesn't work either
coerced_values = [type_coerce(v, JSON) for v is_it_good]

foods = session.query(Food).filter(Food.properties["is_it_good"].in_(coerced_values))
```

However, this works:

```
foods = session.query(Food).filter(Food.properties["is_it_good"] == cast(True, JSON))
```

But this doesn't:

```
foods = session.query(Food).filter(Food.properties["is_it_good"].in_([cast(True, JSON)])
```

Is there a way to make this query work on booleans? Preferably with the `in_` comparison, and preferably with the `type_coerce` approach. The end goal is to have a generic interface where I just pass a json field name and the possible values.

EDIT:

It all boils down to:

```
# This doesn't work
foods = session.query(Food).filter(Food.properties["is_it_good"].in_(type_coerce(True, JSON))

# This works
foods = session.query(Food).filter(Food.properties["is_it_good"].in_(type_coerce(1, JSON))
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out it's a bug/feature with sqlite3. See: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/4969